80's movie about a contest to find the best girls in Los Angeles
Just went to my H.S. reunion, and a group of us were laughing about this movie we watched when we were kids...in the 80's.  A radio station is having a contest to find the best or exciting girls in L.A. The L.A. Rams cheerleaders are featured, some women in an aerobics class are featured..there are more, but I cannot remember.  The girls who end up winning actually skydive topless on the roof of the radio station.  Definitely 80's, obviously made in USA...also the song "Brass in pocket" by the Pretenders is in the movie.

You're looking for California Girls from 1983. From IMDb:

The "plot" (which is just an excuse to show things women do in [Southern California]) is that a local DJ sees his ratings dropping so he comes up with a $10k contest to find the most exciting girl in California. 3 cute girls are listing and try to figure out how to win. They decide being nude is the way to go and first try nude horse riding, then nude roller skating and finally nude skydiving. 

It features music from many famous artists from that era, Including The Pretenders:

